# sst start "TypeError: getAwsCredentials is not a function"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs, serverless-stack

I deleted `/node_modules` and `/package-lock.json` and did `npm install`.

After this when I am doing `npx sst start` I am getting this error:
`TypeError: getAwsCredentials is not a function.`
How to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Package.json

Old:

"@serverless-stack/cli": "0.69.2",

"@serverless-stack/resources": "0.69.2",

New:

"@serverless-stack/cli": "0.69.6",
"@serverless-stack/resources": "0.69.6",

Comment: yeah that worked ... Thank you